# Why is $\lim_{\eta \to \text{cf } \alpha} \omega_{\eta} = \omega_{\alpha}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm reading Jech's Set Theory book and I encountered this problem (Chapter 3 exercise 12).

If $\aleph_\alpha$ is an uncountable limit cardinal, then $\text{cf } \omega_\alpha = \text{cf }  \alpha$; $\omega_\alpha$ is the limit of a cofinal sequence $\langle \omega_{\eta} : \eta < \text{cf }\alpha \rangle.$

My question is, why is the last assertion true? From what I understand, the limit should be $\omega_{\text{cf } \alpha}$ (by definition of $\omega_{\alpha}$ when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal)

Comment: You're right. This is called a typo.

What it should say is that if $\langle\eta_i\mid i<\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\rangle$ is a sequence such that $\lim\eta_i = \alpha$, then $\lim\omega_{\eta_i}=\omega_\alpha$.